# Jenkins hashicorp-vault-plugin empty result

Tags: jenkins, hashicorp-vault

I tried the Jenkins Pipeline Example mentioned here: https://plugins.jenkins.io/hashicorp-vault-plugin

```
node {
    // define the secrets and the env variables
    def secrets = [
        [$class: 'VaultSecret', path: 'secret/testing', secretValues: [
            [$class: 'VaultSecretValue', envVar: 'testing', vaultKey: 'value_one'],
            [$class: 'VaultSecretValue', envVar: 'testing_again', vaultKey: 'value_two']]],
        [$class: 'VaultSecret', path: 'secret/another_test', secretValues: [
        [$class: 'VaultSecretValue', envVar: 'another_test', vaultKey: 'value']]]
    ]

    // optional configuration, if you do not provide this the next higher configuration
    // (e.g. folder or global) will be used
    def configuration = [$class: 'VaultConfiguration',
                         vaultUrl: 'http://my-very-other-vault-url.com',
                         vaultCredentialId: 'my-vault-cred-id']
    // inside this block your credentials will be available as env variables
    wrap([$class: 'VaultBuildWrapper', configuration: configuration, vaultSecrets: secrets]) {
        sh 'echo $testing'
        sh 'echo $testing_again'
        sh 'echo $another_test'
    }
}
```

So I installed hashicorp-vault-plugin 2.2.0 in Jenkins 2.173 and started a Vault (v1.1.1) Docker Container using

```
docker run -d --name vaulttest -p 80:8200 --cap-add=IPC_LOCK -e 'VAULT_DEV_ROOT_TOKEN_ID=myroot' vault
```

Next I configured a token credential within Jenkins using token "myroot"

I created the Secrets within Vault (using the WebUI)

```
testing
   value_one
   value_two
another_test
   value
```

First of all there is an error within the example: When using path "secret/testing" and "secret/another_test" the plugin fails with an error 404:

```
Invalid path for a versioned K/V secrets engine. See the API docs for the appropriate API endpoints to use. If using the Vault CLI, use 'vault kv get' for this operation."
```

This can be fixed when using path "secret/data/testing" and "secret/data/another_test" (see https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-44900)

When then calling the Job the Variables seem to be empty:

```
[Pipeline] sh
+ echo

[Pipeline] sh
+ echo

[Pipeline] sh
+ echo
```

The connection definitely works because when providing invalid credentials or invalid paths I receive errors.

Also retrieving the Secrets directly return a valid response:

```
/ # vault kv get secret/testing
====== Metadata ======
Key              Value
---              -----
created_time     2019-04-17T05:31:23.581020191Z
deletion_time    n/a
destroyed        false
version          3

====== Data ======
Key          Value
---          -----
value_one    HUGO
value_two    BETTY
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As seen here https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-52646 Vault KV V2 returns a different Json Resonse.

So you have to use

```
def secrets = [
    [$class: 'VaultSecret', path: 'secret/data/testing', secretValues: [
        [$class: 'VaultSecretValue', envVar: 'testing', vaultKey: 'data']]]
]
```

to retrieve the correct json response.

The resulting Json-Response can then be passed to "readJSON"

```
def result = readJSON text: testing
echo result.value_one
echo result.value_two
```